# Long website scrollbar JS/CSS problems in wordpress website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Im running a website with premium theme, thing is, last time i installed a copyright widget wich has broken the footer.

So far i've found some wierd jsquery script that may be connected to it, but i've run out of options.

```
element.style {
display:block;
margin-left:0;
margin-top:5400px;
}

<div style="display: block; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 5400px;"/
```

I've also run some tests with default themes, seems like on other ones the situation is opposite. I got huge background (blank) space and i need to scroll down to actually see a website.

[Link](http://shelterpve.tk)

Can anyone point me to a direction? I've literally searched all my WP files, i managed to find some javascripts and i was removing them one by one to check if the problem is resolved but it wasn't. I kinda run out of options and ideas.

Thank you,
Chan

Comment: not sure what this `div` is doing `<div style="display:block; margin-left:0px; margin-top: 5400px;"></div>` but it doesn't have anything in it and appears to be causing the problem. You could remove it from your theme.

Comment: Also, a javascript file called `superfish` isn't loading correctly - so possibly look in to that.

Comment: Where should i look for the div? i've already found the superfish script and removed it, altho i think is in two different locations.

Comment: I wouldn't know specifically where you'd look for it, except in the template files/editor.